# confusions related with infinitive and passive infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I wrote a line in an exam

> Media should be controlled to prevent misuse.

But later I thought "to prevent" is modifying "Media". So I should not have written this because I was trying to say "Media should be controlled so that authority can prevent misuse". But my friends are saying it is a correct sentence. But i dont know why? "to" is working here like "in order to". is this a reason for this?

Comment: It's not clear the misuse of what they are trying to prevent. I think "Media should be controlled to prevent it from misuse." sounds a lot clearer and better.

Comment: When you say "media", do you mean "**the** media", i.e. the organisations that broadcast news information (newspapers, magazines, tv channels, radio shows etc.), or do you mean something else? If you mean "the media", I would use a "the".

Comment: Your friends are right (it's not modifying "media"). The clause "to prevent abuse" is a purpose adjunct in clause structure and "should be controlled" is a 'bare' passive.  And you're right that "to prevent abuse" has the same meaning as "in order to prevent misuse". .

Comment: The infinitive is a purpose infinitive. The test is whether one can substitute _in order to_ for the _to_ infinitive marker. If so, it's a purpose infinitive subordinate clause normally modifying the entire clause it's in. Here it comments on the motives of the agent of _control_ (who is conveniently unmentioned, by virtue of the agentless passive _be controlled_).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear the misuse of what you are trying to prevent. But judging by the context, you're probably talking about the misuse of the media. So, I would rewrite your sentence to make that point clearer:

> The media should be controlled to prevent **its** misuse.

Now, the sentence sounds just perfect.

Comment: I don't think your rephrasing is _quite_ perfect, as I'm not sure it really makes sense. I would rephrase to either: "...to prevent **its** misuse." or "...to prevent it **from being** misused."

Comment: Right, "to prevent its misuse" sounds best. That's what I wanted to write in the first place, but then got carried away trying to come up with something fancier. I'll change it.